# Is there any way to compare Strings lke the "like" in sql?

Tags: java

I want to remove all html tags from the String edit.
For example `"<h1> Hello World </ h1>"` to `"Hello World"`
but with my present replaceAll java transform
`"<h1> Hello World </ h1>"` to `""`.

I would appreciate if someone knows an better and correct way.
Maybe theres an similar to the like function in sql?

```
public void entfTags(){
    String edit = file.getOriginal();
    edit=edit.replaceAll("<br>","\n");
    edit=edit.replaceAll("<\?.*?>", "");
    file.setEdit(edit);
}
```

Comment: Use [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Comment: stackoverflow dont print the htl tags in my question. in my example the program should print the text between two tags, but it removed it too

Comment: @Altzi0 it would if you would use `code block` `<b>example</b>` see?